# Giving option to add item to calendar with HTML - Outlook only

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a CTA in an HTML email, giving people the option to add the certain item to their Outlook Calendar.

To explain it even further; let's assume that I'm sending an email to people in our company to notify their anniversary in the company. I want to send them an automated email (I'll do that with SFMC) with the option to add a half an hour item at 9 o'clock on the day of their anniversary.

Please note that everyone is using the latest Outlook version for their emails, therefore it is the only email client I need to work on.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Simplest solution is probably sending a .ics file as attachment.

Comment: I've checked that, but since I'm thinking about an automated way of doing that, I don't want to create all the .ics files. I was thinking maybe there's an outlook specific code that generates those.